# How do I create a C# style async member in F#?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

In C# you can annotate methods with `async` like this:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public async void Bar()  
    {  

    }  
}
```

This is different to an F# `async`; I believe that in F# these are called *tasks*.

So, how do I write a C#-style `async` member function in F#?

```ml
// Not real code
type Foo () = 
  member async this.Bar () = 
    ()
```

The solution must compile to IL with the same public interface as the C# above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A C# `async` method is just a method returning a value of type `Task<T>`. The C# compiler uses the `async` keyword to determine that you are allowed to use `await` inside the code block, but as far as I know, it is not represented in any way in the compiled code.

You say "the solution must compile to the same IL" - that's not going to be easily possible, because F# implements asynchronous operations differently. However, you can get it to compile to IL that has the same public interface using something like this:

```
type Foo () = 
  member this.Bar () = Async.StartAsTask <| async {
    // yadda yadda 
    }
```

The asynchronous operation is implemented using standard F# async workflow, so under the cover, this creates an F# `Async<T>`, but the `Async.StartAsTask` operation turns that into a `Task<T>` type, which is what C# expects.

**EDIT:** Another alternative is to use the [TaskBuilder computation expression](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs), which lets you directly create .NET tasks using something like this:

```
type Foo () = 
  member this.Bar () = task {
    // yadda yadda 
    }
```

Comment: The same public interface is suffcient.

Comment: FYI: If you flag a method as `async` then the method will have the `AsyncStateMachine` attribute on it.

Answer (score 0):

Async.StartAsTask should do it.  This will give you Threading.Tasks.Task<'a>

```
let bar  =
    async{
        
        return ()
    }
    |>Async.StartAsTask
```